# Slick slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I've used slick slider before, but now I don't what causes this ruckus.
Am I missing something? I've followed the instruction at slick slider and also at github, I'm puzzled.

```js
//JS here
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows:true,
  autoplaySpeed:1000
});
```

```css
/* Style here */
.container{
   max-width:1200px;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Script -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<!-- Html -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="slider">

   <div class="slides">
    <img src="Picture4" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="slides">
    <img src="Picture3" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="slides">
    <img src="Picture2" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="slides">
    <img src="Picture1" alt="">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/WAWI/pen/VBQOrd

Here is the link

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing your code, I noticed that the slick css import was missing.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css
```

I leave your example below with the CSS import.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows:true,
  autoplaySpeed:1000
});
```

```css
.container{
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.slider{
  display:flex;
  .slides{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- this line is missing -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bro, I appreciate it.

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider